# SVG android library

Tags: android, svg, svg-android

I am using com.larvalabs.svgandroid library. It works fine however only with SVG images made by Adobe Illustrator. I tried Inkscape and online online-convert SVG convertor however none of those outputs worked. Is there any free software that produces SVG file which is familiar to this library?

Comment: Try my library.  It renders illustrator files fine.  https://code.google.com/p/androidsvg/

Comment: I use the applantation flavour of `svg-android`. It works with Inkscape files as well. Just save them as **plain svg**. Some fixes are to be done to the SVGs (mostly optimizations to Inkscape SVG produced code).